# What is the difference between an ampliative and explanatory reasoning?

Tags: logic, aristotle, frege

I'm reading "Reason's nearest kin" of michael potter and he says:

> Now the distinctive feature of reasoning that is ampliative rather than
>   merely explicative is that it depends on objects as its subject matter.
>   If polyadic logic is ampliative, it must therefore depend on objects in a
>   way that syllogistic logic does not. The feature which makes this dependence
>   manifest is the variable.

Can you develop further on the difference between ampliative and explanatory reasoning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ampliatian is, according to ch. 14 of John of St. Thomas's [*Outlines of Formal Logic*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5156),

> "the extension of a term from a lesser to a greater supposition." For example, *Man can be just* is extended to possible men.

Explanation (*[explicare](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=explicare)*) literally means "to unfold, uncoil, unroll, unfurl, unclose," etc. what is already there. But with ampliation something new is added (in John of St. Thomas's example: what it means for a possible man to be just, etc.).